# Webview in TabHost = Starting as black screen

Tags: android, webview, android-tabhost

I'm trying to use a webview inside a tabhost that has 4 tabs - all linked to the same webview.

This is great except for one problem: 
At start up the webview is black. 
Clicking tab 2,3 or 4 makes it "come alive".

My quick fix was to use setCurrentTab(1) and then back to 0, but this looks ugly, so I figured I might as well ask for a solution as I cannot find anything online.

How can this be fixed? Below is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <android.webkit.WebView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/webview" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:scrollbars="none"/>
    </FrameLayout>
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        />
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

**Update:**
Putting the webview outside of the framelayout causes the app to crash at startup with following error: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create tab content because could not find view with id 2131099648

This happens when I in the onCreate method initialize my tabhost like this:

```
    mTabHost = getTabHost();
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1").setIndicator("Tab1", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ligenu)).setContent(R.id.webview));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test2").setIndicator("Tab2", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mad)).setContent(R.id.webview));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test3").setIndicator("Tab3", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.godpris)).setContent(R.id.webview));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test4").setIndicator("Tab4", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.om)).setContent(R.id.webview));
```

Comment: Remove it from the `FrameLayout`. Add it as a child of the `LinearLayout`

Comment: Will this still let me control it through my tabhost?

Comment: Great, i'll give that a try tonight then :) If it works I'll post here, and you can post your solution as an answer to get the bounty.

Comment: Hmm simply moving the webview from framelayout and putting it inside the linearlayout makes the app force close at startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break through!

I found the answer to my own question in another SO post that I didn't stumble upon in the past:
[Why is my TabHost's FrameLayout's only child loaded with visibility = View.GONE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109081/why-is-my-tabhosts-framelayouts-only-child-loaded-with-visibility-view-gone)

Simply setting:

```
tabHost.getCurrentView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

That fix the issue!

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problem. As suggested, I put **tabHost.getCurrentView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);** to the code, the webview still come out blank. After a few more searches, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214143/webview-not-shown-inside-tabhost-on-honeycomb-when-open-tab-first-time) saved me. It turns out that it's important to set **android:layout_height="wrap_content"** to the webview.